# vb.net string lookup in listbox with output as different part of the string

Tags: vb.net

Last Name Finder

what I'm trying to do is create a list of all peoples surnames where the 1st name = @name
although this isn't the exact purpose its easier to try and explain the actual content. i'm aware it may be easier to use a data source, but I want to try and avoid that where possible.

```
Form_Load
ListBox1.Items.Add("Dean Smith")
ListBox1.Items.Add("John Jones")
ListBox1.Items.Add("David Johnson")
ListBox1.Items.Add("Samantha Thompson")
ListBox1.Items.Add("Claire Frost")
ListBox1.Items.Add("John Brown")
```

and then some sort of string manipulation to do the following on button_click

```
 if textbox1.text contains "John" then
  listbox2.items.add(Jones)
  listbox2.items.add(Brown)
else messagebox.show("No matches found")
end if
```

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1):

What I've understood is that you are willing to use your textbox as a filter to the listbox. And this can be achieved by running the query to your db on every TextChanged().

So to give you some guidelines, you can proceed like this;

```
 private Names As List(Of String)

 Private Sub Form2_Load1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Names = New List(Of String)

    With Names
        .Add("Dean Smith")
        .Add("John Jones")
        .Add("John Brown")
    End With

    For Each Name As String In Names
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Name)
    Next 

 End sub

 Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged


        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        For Each s As String In Names

            If s.Substring(0, TextBox1.Text.Length).ToLower = TextBox1.Text.ToLower Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add(s)
            End If
        Next 


  End Sub
```

I hope this solution might help you achieve what you wanted. You can also apply direct filter to the List by using a delegate function, which will avoid you from looping again on TextChange().

Comment: that's perfect, although it adds the whole name I only want it to add the string after the space so if its Dean Smith just add Smith